# Unhiding UITextFields with data in Swift

Tags: swift3

I’m trying to build an app for work where I can input various jobs for each machine.  I have a total of 9 UITextFields that are hidden when the view loads.  I have an add job button that will unhide a field as to enter text.  I also have a save button which will save the data to UserDefaults.  My problem is when I save the data and quit the app. When the view loads the UITextFields are hidden again. I can press the add job button and it appears along with the data that was saved.  What I would like, is to have the UITextFields remain visible if there was text in them before the quitting the app. I can’t seem to figure out how to make that happen. I’m very new to programming and would very much appreciate any help that you could offer.

```
     var addJobButtonPressed = 0
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


     @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField4: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField5: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField6: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField7: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField8: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var textField9: UITextField!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         textField1.isHidden = true
         textField2.isHidden = true
         textField3.isHidden = true
         textField4.isHidden = true
         textField5.isHidden = true
         textField6.isHidden = true
         textField7.isHidden = true
         textField8.isHidden = true
         textField9.isHidden = true

         textField1.text = defaults.object(forKey: "Job1") as? String
         textField2.text = defaults.object(forKey: "Job2") as? String

      }

     @IBAction func addJobButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
           addJobButtonPressed += 1
           if addJobButtonPressed == 1 {
           self.textField1.isHidden = false
       }
    }


     @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
           defaults.set(textField1.text, forKey: "Job1")
           defaults.set(textField2.text, forKey: "Job2")
           defaults.synchronize()

       }
```

Comment: "My problem is when I save the data and quit the app. When the view loads the UITextFields are hidden again" Why don't you store the hidden state of each text field in `defaults` along with the texts?

Comment: By the way, any time you have names like `textField1`, `textField2`, `Job1`, `Job2`, you're doing it wrong. You want an _array_.

Comment: you could save the individual textfield's state in a .plist or property list file. ( There's plenty of tutorials) When the view loads it can read the file. if there are only 8 or 9 textfields involved there's no need to use complex things like CoreData. At the beginning stage of writing your app, you should investigate making an array of your textfields. That way the machine number relates directly to the array index number ( watch your zero ) without a long conditional structure. I'm curious about what platform uses swift to talk to turnkey solutions, is this manually entered by a human?

Answer (score 2):

**Replace** `viewDidLoad()` **with this method:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    updateTextFieldsVisibility()


}
```

**Add following two methods:**

```
func updateTextFieldsVisibility(){

    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField1, key: "Job1")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField2, key: "Job2")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField3, key: "Job3")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField4, key: "Job4")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField5, key: "Job5")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField6, key: "Job6")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField7, key: "Job7")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField8, key: "Job8")
    updateTextFieldText(textField: textField9, key: "Job9")

}


func updateTextFieldText(textField: UITextField, key: String){

    if defaults.object(forKey: key) != nil {

        textField.isHidden = false
        textField.text = defaults.object(forKey: key) as? String

    }
    else{

        textField.isHidden = true
    }

}
```

Though it can be done by `viewWithTag` property or `IBOutletArray` but this simple steps make you understand what you are looking for.

Happy coding.